# Email service not working when Email sent from Outlook Web App

Tags: apex-email-service, outlook

I have a created an Email service in Salesforce. It is working as expected when I send emails from any email client. But when the email is sent from Outlook Web Access (OWA), email are not processed. I am not sure if emails are being sent to Salesforce or not, it doesn't give any error as well.

Comment: Do you see any activity if you setup debug log?  If that doesn't help, you might have to work with Salesforce support as they can troubleshoot and see if email even received and if it is in wrong format.

Comment: No debug log is generated. That is why I am not able to get to a solution. @datasert